# connecting 2 GNDs with relative voltage difference

Tags: current, usb, voltage-reference

I have USB ground and Lab Voltage Source ground, for which I need common reference. I thought I could just connect them together, but I found, that USB ground is relatively higher than Voltage Source ground (1.5 V difference). Even more interesting was the current measurement ("short-circuiting" those 1.5V with Ampere-meter), that yielded only 4 mA.

Question:

What is going on when the 2 grounds (that are relatively different) are connected together?

Why there is such small current between terminals that have 1.5 V difference? Shouldnt  short-circuiting them produce high(er) current? (relatively higher - e.g. USB can handle up to 500 mA)

Comment: Was it an ac voltage of 1.5 volts you measured?

Comment: Hint: I power my 2V LED with a 12V/2A wallwart and a resistor limiting the current to 12mA. Now I short circuit the LED (that I measure 2V over), what current will flow?

Comment: to Andy aka: It is DC
to PlasmaHH: but voltage source (the voltage that would be measured on the diode) has to provide stable voltage. E.G. battery doesnt change its voltage (significantly, assuming normal conditions) depending on load. In your case, there is voltage devider changing output voltage depending on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is resistance in those paths that is limiting the current flow (as noted in the comments above). since you don't really know why there was an offset to begin with you don't know what is in those signal paths either. But you now have characterized that path enough to know that is has to be kilo-ohms of resistance!

Comment: Well, but there arises a problem. When I assume that the ground has a resistence (in series with load), then there is voltage devider. The outcome would be a voltage source that changes according to connected load.